# how to setup system wide SOCKET4 proxy in Windows 10 including UWP apps?

Tags: networking, windows-10, proxy

So far I have tried

- Proxyfier. It only worked for user apps even though I gave admin permission [DID NOT WORK]
- proxy config inside Settings. [DID NOT WORK]
- Used proxy to Internet option. It worked in internet explorer and other software but not in UWP app ex: windows store.  [DID NOT WORK]. It
- Used proxy with powershell command

> netsh winhttp set proxy myproxy:port

[DID NOT WORK]

> netsh winhttp import proxy source =ie
>    [DID NOT WORK]

Now what should I do to set up SOCKET4 proxy to whole system. Basically I just want to use proxy to use Microsoft Store.

Answer (score 0):

See the Github project of
[EnableProxyForUWP](https://github.com/Ricardo-Evans/EnableProxyForUWP):

> **EnableProxyForUWP**
>
> To enable proxy for UWP applications of windows 10.
>
> **Usage**
>
> Simply download the jar file and run it as administrator, then you
>   will be able to proxy all your uwp applications.

It requires Java.

Comment: it doesn't work. It does nothing

Comment: Where do you see that UWP apps do not use the proxy? Note that for IPv6 and UDP you need [SOCKS5](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOCKS#SOCKS5).

Comment: I tried to execute the jar file. but it shows nothing. Maybe it crashed. Or did I miss anything?